# How to avoid key column name duplication in join?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to join two tables in spark sql. Each table has 50+ columns. Both has column `id` as the key.

```
spark.sql("select * from tbl1 join tbl2 on tbl1.id = tbl2.id")
```

The joined table has duplicated `id` column.
We can of course specify which `id` column to keep like below:

```
spark.sql("select tbl1.id, .....from tbl1 join tbl2 on tbl1.id = tbl2.id")
```

But since we have so many columns in both tables, I do not want to type all the other column names in the query above. (other than `id` column, no other duplicated column names).

what should I do? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If `id` is the only column name in common, you can take advantage of the `USING` clause:

```
spark.sql("select * from tbl1 join tbl2 using (id) ")
```

The `using` clause matches columns that have the same name in both tables.  When using `select *`, the column appears only once.

Comment: `Undefined function: 'using'`   There is no using clause in spark sql.  @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @zesla . . . That might be the version you are using.  There is definitely an `using` clause:  https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-join.html.

Comment: Worked fine in 3.1.2. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you want to preserve the "duplicates", you can try to use the internal row-id or equivalents for your help. This helped me in the past, if I had to delete exactly one of two identical rows.

```
select *,ctid from table;
```

outputs in postgresql also the internal counter id. Your before exact identical rows become different now. I don't know about spark.sql, but I assume, that you can access a similar attribute there.

Answer (score 0):

```scala
val joined = spark
     .sql("select * from tbl1")
     .join(
          spark.sql("select * from tbl2"),
          Seq("id"),
          "inner" // optional
     )
```

`joined` should have only one `id` column. Tested with Spark 2.4.8